# URL redirect IIS with subdomain and subfolder test fine, but produce 404

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis, web-config

I created a URL Redirect entry. First tried manually, couldn't get it to work. Then I used the IIS interface to create one. Ran all tests and they say they pass. I get an 404 error now though.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="subdomain redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(?!www)(.*).domain.nl/(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www)(.*)\.domain\.nl\/(.*)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.nl/external/Login.aspx?org={C:2}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

If I go to http://foo.domain.nl/AnyExistingPage.aspx, it all works fine.
There is no redirect happening.

So the goal is to redirect this URL: http://foo.domain.nl/stack
The the following URL: http://www.domain.nl/external/Login.aspx?org=stack

In other words when the subdomain is NOT www, then take the subfolder as parameter for the redirect URL. If pages for the rest don't work on foo.domain.nl, that is fine.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<rules>
    <rule name="subdomain redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.domain.nl" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.nl/external/Login.aspx?org={R:0}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
```